# Docker-compose fails on mounting node & redis instance

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, redis

im trying to build a simple docker-compose instance to learn about its usage, my intention its to build a docker container with a node alpine image running on it, and a simple web api counting the visits number, redis would be the software conunting the visits but from another container, using docker-compose to build them 2gether

Those are the files involved:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json . RUN npm install COPY . .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express'); const redis = require('redis');

const app = express(); const client = redis.createClient({ host: 'redis-server', port: 6379, }); client.set('visits', 0);

app.get('/', (req, res) => { client.get('visits', (err, visits) => { res.send('Number of visits ' + visits); client.set('visits', parseInt(visits) + 1); }); });

app.listen(8081, () => { console.log('listening on port 8081'); });
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "redis": "2.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
  node-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '4001:8081'
```

if i build the docker image for the node container, it works fine and i can run it with no issue:

```
[root@censured visits]# docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 30.72 kB
Step 1/6 : FROM node:14-alpine
 ---> 937e8a02e5c7
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR '/app'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 59446d255778
Step 3/6 : COPY package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4ec3946ad72c
Step 4/6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a0f65574b8d2
Step 5/6 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3b094de2b762
Step 6/6 : CMD npm start
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7e81148dcce4
Successfully built 7e81148dcce4
```

and i can run this node container with no issue, but if i use docker-compose to run it alongside a redis instance this happens:

```
[root@censured visits]# docker-compose up
Creating network "visits_default" with the default driver
Creating visits_node-app_1     ... done
Creating visits_redis-server_1 ... done
Attaching to visits_node-app_1, visits_redis-server_1
redis-server_1  | 1:C 10 Aug 2022 10:55:32.989 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis-server_1  | 1:C 10 Aug 2022 10:55:32.989 # Redis version=7.0.4, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis-server_1  | 1:C 10 Aug 2022 10:55:32.990 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis-server_1  | 1:M 10 Aug 2022 10:55:32.993 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
redis-server_1  | 1:M 10 Aug 2022 10:55:32.996 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis-server_1  | 1:M 10 Aug 2022 10:55:32.996 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
redis-server_1  | 1:M 10 Aug 2022 10:55:32.996 # Server initialized
redis-server_1  | 1:M 10 Aug 2022 10:55:32.996 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis-server_1  | 1:M 10 Aug 2022 10:55:32.998 * Ready to accept connections
node-app_1      |
node-app_1      | > @ start /app
node-app_1      | > node index.js
node-app_1      |
node-app_1      | /app/index.js:7
node-app_1      |   port: 6379
node-app_1      |   ^^^^
node-app_1      |
node-app_1      | SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
node-app_1      |     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
node-app_1      |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
node-app_1      |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
node-app_1      |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
node-app_1      |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
node-app_1      |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
node-app_1      |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
node-app_1      | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
node-app_1      | npm ERR! errno 1
node-app_1      | npm ERR! @ start: `node index.js`
node-app_1      | npm ERR! Exit status 1
node-app_1      | npm ERR!
node-app_1      | npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
node-app_1      | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
node-app_1      |
node-app_1      | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
node-app_1      | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-08-10T10_55_34_082Z-debug.log
visits_node-app_1 exited with code 1
```

Redis server seems to be running well but Node server doesn't, any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: In your non-Compose setup, you build the image but don't run it.  If you `docker run 7e81148dcce4` do you get the same error?  If you run `node index.js` on the host without Docker, do you get the same error?

Comment: i can run  it with no issue: 


[root@censured visits]# docker run 7e81148dcce4

> @ start /app
> node index.js

listening on port 8081